# Accessing SQL Server with VB6

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I am trying to display data stored in SQL server in VB6.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ledger] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
select a.StockMaster,sum1,sum2,(sum2-sum1) as TQty from
(SELECT tblStockMaster.SmName AS StockMaster, SUM(isnull(tblReceivingD.TotalQuantity,0)) AS sum2
FROM tblStockMaster LEFT JOIN tblReceivingD ON tblReceivingD.StockControlR=tblStockMaster.SmName
GROUP BY tblStockMaster.SmName) a ,
(SELECT tblStockMaster.SmName AS StockMaster, SUM(isnull(tblPurchaseOrderD.TotalQuantity,0)) AS sum1
FROM tblStockMaster LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseOrderD ON tblPurchaseOrderD.StockControl=tblStockMaster.SmName GROUP BY tblStockMaster.SmName) b
where a.StockMaster =b.StockMaster
```

While in VB6 the SQL cannot be found. How can I connect to the SQL database? Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
SetGrid
recdisplay "ledger"
End Sub
Function SetGrid()


With MSFlexGrid1
    .Rows = 1

    .ColWidth(0) = 0
    .ColWidth(1) = 4650: .TextMatrix(0, 1) = "Item Name"
    .ColWidth(2) = 3565: .TextMatrix(0, 2) = "Total Quantity"
    End With
End Function



Function recdisplay(sql As Variant)
```

The error says:

> > item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

```
Dim R As Integer
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

With MSFlexGrid1
.Rows = 1

    While Not rs.EOF
     .AddItem rs!SMControl & vbTab & rs!SmName & vbTab & rs!tqty

     rs.MoveNext
     Wend

End With
End Function
```

Comment: stick a break point on your 'With MSFlexGrid1' line, go to your Immediate window and type: rs.Save "c:\rs.xml",adPersistXML  ...this will write your record set to xml so you can examine it outside your code

Answer (score 2):

You stored proc returns the following columns:

- `StockMaster`
- `sum1`
- `sum2`
- `TQty`

Your VB6 code is trying to use the following names in the `rs` Recordset object:

- `SMControl`
- `qty`

So I think the error is saying that `SMControl` is not a valid name for a `Field` in your Recordset object. I would guess you need to change `SMControl`to `StockMaster` in your VB6 code.

Comment: You need to accept the correct answer since those who don't give credit end up never getting further help.